# Short hand for [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, singleton

I stored global variables in my AppDelegate and access them by:

```
AppDelegate *d = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
d.someString = ...
```

What's the recommend way to save some typing and so I don't need to `AppDelegate *d = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` again and again? Thanks!

Comment: import your AppDelege into your pch file. By doing this you don't need to import in every file and you can get this macro anywhere across your project.

Comment: Note that if you find yourself typing `AppDelegate *d = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` again and again, that might be a code smell. Do you really need the app delegate for app-delegate-ish things, or are you using it as a dumping ground for global state?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As *Shaggy Frog* said, define a macro in your YourAppDelegate.h file, an example like this:

```
#define AppDelegate (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Then you can get the app delegate in your code like this:

```
[AppDelegate ......];
```

Comment: This. This is the best solution.

Comment: Don't you need to wrap it in parenthesis like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549410/define-the-app-delegate-as-a-constant]?

Comment: Also, make sure that "AppDelegate" and "YourAppDelegate" are different words.  Sometimes "YourAppDelegate", that is the name of your app delegate defaults to simply "AppDelegate".

Answer (score 11):

Since your app delegate never really changes, you can create an external that you define in the app delegate code, very similar to the `NSApp` external for Mac OS X Cocoa applications.

So, define the external in your AppDelegate header (or something else that you would include everywhere):

```
extern AppDelegate* appDelegate;
```

Then create it and set it in your implementation file:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = nil;

// later -- i can't recall the actual method name, but you get the idea
- (BOOL)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options
{
  appDelegate = self;
  // do other stuff
  return YES;
}
```

Then other classes can just access it:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// later
- (void)doSomethingGreat
{
  NSDictionary* mySettings = [appDelegate settings];
  if( [[mySettings objectForKey:@"stupidOptionSet"] boolValue] ) {
    // do something stupid
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as the dot notation accessors worked with this solution

Answer (score 8):

You could just create a C-style macro and put it in a header file somewhere.

(As for using your app delegate as a giant global variable catch-all, that's another rant for another day.)

Answer (score 4):

I create a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) called **UIApplication+delegate** with some convenience messages in it.  Getting my specific delegate being one of the convenience messages.  So, for instance, if my app delegate was called **MyAppDelegate**, it would look like this:

**UIApplication+delegate.h**

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface UIApplication(delegate)
+ (MyAppDelegate *)thisApp;
@end
```

and **UIApplication+delegate.m**

```
#import "UIApplication+delegate.h"


@implementation UIApplication(delegate)

+ (MyAppDelegate *)thisApp {
    return (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

@end
```

In a class that needs the delegate, I do this:

```
#import "UIApplication+delegate.h"

...

- (void)doStuff {
    MyAppDelegate *app = [UIApplication thisApp];
    // use "app"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also created a category, except that I applied mine to NSObject so any object in the application can easily get to the delegate.

---

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface NSObject(delegate)
- (MyAppDelegate *) appDelegate;
@end
```

---

```
#import "NSObject+delegate.h"

@implementation UIApplication(delegate)

- (MyAppDelegate *)appDelegate {
    return (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

@end
```

---