# Define the app delegate as a constant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I'm trying to write an iPhone application, and I have a problem.
I have declared a constant as the app delegate inside a class

```
#define ikub (iKubMobileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

And when I need to get the size of an array, which is an instance variable for the application

```
[ikub.subscriptions count]
```

I get an error **Accessing unknown 'subscriptions' getter method**.
I'm not really sure why this is happening.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Make sure you have imported the `iKubMobileAppDelegate.h` file into your files that are using your app delegate. And check that your app delegate has a `subscriptions` property. Also, C preprocessor macros tend to be named in `ALL_CAPS` as a convention.

Comment: Checked all of the above and they're all ok. Also, changed the constant to all caps just to be 1000% sure, but I get the same error. :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to wrap your macro value in parentheses (otherwise, the cast within the macro applies to the property, which at that point is unknown.) So:

```
#define ikub ((iKubMobileAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

Comment: I suggest an inline function instead of a macro. That way you can set breakpoints properly, and avoid macro-specific trickery like the above. Something like static inline iKubMobileAppDelegate* ikub() { return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; }

Comment: Careful. `()` in pure C/Objective-C means something different from `(void)`. In this case, he'd want `static inline iKubMobileAppDelegate  *ikub(void)`. :)

Comment: Great answer but can you elaborate of what cast within macro?

Comment: @JimThio I don't understand your question.

Comment: You said the cast within the macro applies to the property. What property? What cast? Which one? Thanks it'll help me to understand.

Comment: There's only one cast and only one property used in the macro. So those.